# How do I determine shell execution context of a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, windows, command-line

Is there a way to programmatically determine if a Ruby script is being run from the Windows DOS shell, Linux bash shell etc.?

I am trying to emit ANSI colour codes on any console that supports it. I have used the term-ansicolor gem along with win32console to translate ANSI colour codes to native Windows command line colour sequences. However, I have found this solution to be quite flaky.

I want to emit ANSI on ANSI-capable consoles only (note this script is run on Windows and Linux with various alternate third-party shells).

Comment: This sounds a lot like an XY Problem[http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem] question. Please ask question X.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use parent process id to determine where it was started from. You can get parent process id using `Process` module. However beware of this warning (Returns untrustworthy value on Win32/64.) on [Process.ppid](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-ppid), you'll need to thoroughly test this solution. Once you have parent process id, you do a lookup on `win32_process` table to get the name of process and just check if its `cmd.exe`. Sample code below.

```
require 'win32ole'

wmi = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://")
processes = wmi.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where ProcessId = #{Process.ppid}")

processes.each do |process|
    if process.Name == "cmd.exe"
        puts "started from command prompt. Do something"
    else
        puts "started from elsewhere. Do something else"
    end     
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this will not work on Linux will it? My script runs on Windows and Linux.

Comment: ok you never mentioned Linux in your question. You are right it will not work on linux as it is. You'll need to modify above code to first find out which OS you're running this script on, you can do this using `uname` on both windows (provided you have devkit installed, else use `systeminfo` on windows) as well as linux. After you have identified OS, check win32_process table for windows and `ps` on linux to find out parent process name.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know how I go.